# string.match() returns a String instead of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I've been using Javascript `string.match(*regex*)` function to parse the `navigator.userAgent` string.

FYI, According to MDN & W3schools:

> "The match() method searches a string for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches, as an **Array object**."

I first parse once to get the wanted strings for the base string:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
var splitted = userAgent.match(/[(][^)]+[)]|\w+\/\S+/ig);
```

Which gives me the following Output (Which is an Array)

```
Mozilla/5.0
(Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3)
AppleWebKit/537.36
(KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/41.0.2272.76
Safari/537.36
```

Then i parse the *Navigator/Version* type strings in a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++ ) {
    var str = splitted[i];
    if (str[0] == '(') {
    } else {
        var name = str.match(/[^\/]+/i);
        var version = str.match(/[0-9|\.]+/i);
}
```

But, very surprisingly and even though I get the desired result, **I get a String Object for the *name* and an Array Object for the *version***

How is it even possible ?

Here's the snippet of the code ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baxnLyhL/1/)):

```js
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
var splitted = userAgent.match(/[(][^)]+[)]|\w+\/\S+/ig);
var outputDiv = document.getElementById("log");

for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++ ) {
  var str = splitted[i];
  if (str[0] == '(') {
  } else {
    var name = str.match(/[^\/]+/i);
    var version = str.match(/[0-9|\.]+/i);
    outputDiv.innerHTML += name.toString() + " is a " + typeof(name) + "<br>";
    outputDiv.innerHTML += version.toString() + " is a " + typeof(version) + "<br>";
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

--- UPDATE ---

Thanks **FactoryAidan** for the answer, it was a scope problem.

**Conclusion: be careful when naming global variables :)**

Comment: Start using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for looking at JavaScript docs.

Comment: also there's no way a match can return a string.

Comment: Offtopic cultural advice: In english, use the term "Dear" to address a *very* formal letter, and to refer to our husbands/wives. ;) Ive edited out the slightly creepy opening line.

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: `.match()` can only return `Array` or `null`.

Comment: Without the `/g` flag, `match` returns captured groups instead of every match. (e.g. `"test".match(/te(st)/)` is `["test", "st"]`.) That’s a one-element array here, but still an array.

Comment: @epascarello I use both, so I edited the post a bit to avoid this kind of comment :)

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks for your correction. In fact I'm french so every cultural/language advices are welcome :)

Comment: @Jamiec this might be due to cultural difference, but why I emphasised "our" is, that I thought, why would OP use the term "Dear" to refer to other's wives/husbands. He should be doing with *his* wife. Again, I ain't native English speaker. Cleaning it up.

Comment: @ElieZgala: Can you please log and post the value of `str`, as well as how `version` looks like a string object??

Comment: If MDN is the reference, W3schools isn't really a trusted source (but it progresses) and has no relation with the W3C

Comment: On your 'UPDATE' you only changed to `my_name` on the variable assignment. But you didn't change `name` to `my_name` on the `outputDiv.innerHTML = ` lines.  So this is not going to output what you think it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Global Variable Scope

It is because you are using `name` as your variable. This is a global browser window variable that is inherently a string and cannot be stored as an Array

Even if you redeclare it with `var name =`, you are still in the global scope. And thus `name` (aka `window.name`) simply retains the last value you assign to it.

You can test this with the following on an empty page without defining any variables at all:

```
console.log(name===window.name) // Returns true
console.log(name,window.name)   // Returns 'Safari Safari' for my browser
```

---

### Change `name` to something else

If you change your `name` variable to simply have a different name, like `my_name`, it stores the result of `.match()` as an Array.

```
var my_name = str.match(/[^\/]+/i);
var version = str.match(/[0-9|\.]+/i);

console.log(typeof my_name, my_name instanceof Array) // Returns object, true
```

---

### Change Scope by wrapping in a function

This is your exact code wrapped inside a function and returns the correct variable types:

```
function getBrowserStuff(){

    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    var splitted = userAgent.match(/[(][^)]+[)]|\w+\/\S+/ig);

    for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++ ) {
        var str = splitted[i];
        if (str[0] == '(') {
        } else {
            var name = str.match(/[^\/]+/i);
            var version = str.match(/[0-9|\.]+/i);
            console.log('Name','Typeof '+(typeof name), 'IsArray '+(name instanceof Array),name)
            console.log('Version','Typeof '+(typeof version),'IsArray '+(version instanceof Array),version)
        }
    }

    return 'whatever'
}

getBrowserStuff()
```

---

Changing the variable `name` to `my_name` **OR** wrapping code like the above function returns this:

```
Name    Typeof object IsArray true ["Mozilla"]
Version Typeof object IsArray true ["5.0"]
Name    Typeof object IsArray true ["AppleWebKit"]
Version Typeof object IsArray true ["600.3.18"]
Name    Typeof object IsArray true ["Version"]
Version Typeof object IsArray true ["8.0.3"]
Name    Typeof object IsArray true ["Safari"]
Version Typeof object IsArray true ["600.3.18"]
```

Where before it returned this:

```
Name    Typeof string IsArray false Mozilla
Version Typeof object IsArray true  ["5.0"]
Name    Typeof string IsArray false AppleWebKit
Version Typeof object IsArray true  ["600.3.18"]
Name    Typeof string IsArray false Version
Version Typeof object IsArray true  ["8.0.3"]
Name    Typeof string IsArray false Safari
Version Typeof object IsArray true  ["600.3.18"]
```

Comment: No, instead of changing the variable name better simply wrap the code in a function. It's already declared with  `var` anyway.

Comment: You must not have done it right, I edited your code by changing `name` to `my_name` and get the right variable type.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Interesting, +1. Specifically, the problem is that `window.name` has a setter that stores the stringified value. Since the property is configurable, this can be bypassed with `Object.defineProperty`. But better avoid global variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, or is a bug of your implementation.

According to the ECMAScript 5.1 specification, `match` behaves like this:

> [**15.5.4.10 String.prototype.match (regexp)**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10)
>
> When the `match` method is called with argument *regexp*, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Call [CheckObjectCoercible](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.10) passing the this value as its argument.
> 2. Let *S* be the result of calling [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8), giving it the this value as its argument.
> 3. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*regexp*) is Object and the value of the [[Class]] internal property of *regexp* is "`RegExp`", then let *rx* be
>      *regexp*;
> 4. Else, let *rx* be a new RegExp object created as if by the expression `new RegExp(`*regexp*`)` where `RegExp` is the standard
>      built-in constructor with that name.
> 5. Let *global* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of *rx* with argument "`global`".
> 6. Let *exec* be the standard built-in function `RegExp.prototype.exec` ([see 15.10.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2))
> 7. If *global* is not **true**, then
>
>    1. Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of *exec* with *rx* as the **this** value and argument list containing *S*.
> 8. Else, *global* is **true**
>
>    1. Call the [[Put]] internal method of *rx* with arguments "`lastIndex`" and 0.
>    2. Let *A* be a new array created as if by the expression `new Array()` where `Array` is the standard built-in constructor with that
>         name.
>    3. Let *previousLastIndex* be 0.
>    4. Let *n* be 0.
>    5. Let *lastMatch* be **true**.
>    6. Repeat, while *lastMatch* is **true**
>
>       1. Let *resul*t be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of *exec* with *rx* as the **this** value and argument list
>            containing *S*.
>       2. If *result* is **null**, then set *lastMatch* to **false**.
>       3. Else, *result* is not **null**
>
>          1. Let *thisIndex* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of *rx* with argument "`lastIndex`".
>          2. If *thisIndex* = *previousLastIndex* then
>
>             1. Call the [[Put]] internal method of *rx* with arguments "`lastIndex`" and *thisIndex*+1.
>             2. Set *previousLastIndex* to *thisIndex*+1.
>          3. Else, set *previousLastIndex* to *thisIndex*.
>          4. Let *matchStr* be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of *result* with argument "`0`".
>          5. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *A* with arguments [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)(*n*), the [Property Descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10)
>               {[[Value]]: *matchStr*, [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]:
>               **true**, [[configurable]]: **true**}, and **false**.
>          6. Increment *n*.
>    7. If *n* = 0, then return **null**.
>    8. Return *A*.

Therefore, for your global regex, the only possible returned values are **null** or *A*, which is an array.

For the non global ones, the result of calling [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2) is returned. But it also returns an array or **null**:

> Performs a regular expression match of *string* against the regular
>   expression and returns an Array object containing the results of the
>   match, or **null** if *string* did not match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure if I understand: Is it impossible or is it explained by using a non-global regex ?
Thanks